# formulas in bold theorem titles in ntheorem package

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I'm not quite sure if this counts as a bug or a feature but I have the following problem with the `ntheorem` package. The theorem title is bold face, which I like, but in math formulas setting some (or all) letters to bold may change the meaning of the mathematical quantities (vectors are bold, scalars are normal etc)

So my question: how can I avoid that the mathematical formulas in the title of the theorem are changed but the rest of the title is still set in bold?

As far as I can see the problem does not occur in the (obsolete) theorem package.

Comment: this is, at the very least, a design flaw for the reason you mention.  this problem does not occur in the `amsthm` package.  (the [optional] part of the theorem header there isn't normally bold at all, which some non-ams people feel is a design flaw.  but even if this is overcome by a `\newtheoremstyle`, the math still won't be bold.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `boldmath` is inserted by

```
\def\theorem@checkbold{\if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\boldmath\fi}
```

so it looks as if you could go

```
\makeatletter

\def\theorem@checkbold{}

\makeatother
```

to disable that feature

Comment: @StefanWaldmann: If that does the job, you can accept the answer given by David.